# If B is bounded above and b = sup(B), show that $b \notin U $

Tags: general-topology

Let $U\subset \Bbb R$ is an open subset; for every $z \in U$, there is an $r > 0 $ such that $ (z-r, z+r) \subset U $.

Let $x \in U $. Define B = {$ y: [x, y) \subset U$}

If B is bounded above and b = sup(B), show that $b \notin U $.

Sol:

Since b = sup(B), for all $y \in B$, $ y \le b$.

I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

What if $b \in U$? Then by definition there exists an r such that $(b-r,b+r) \in U$ and hence b would not be the supremum of B.

Comment: What do you mean b is not sup(B)? Can you clarify it?

Comment: Are you saying if I choose a y such that $ b \lt y  \le b+r $, b will not be supremum?

Comment: yes that is precisely it.